# Will keyword stuffing on the front page affect other pages?

Tags: seo, keywords, keyword-stuffing

Say that www.onlyasamlple.com has keyword stuffed on "sample".
Will this stuffing reduce the ranking for www.onlyasample.com/othersample on "sample" as well?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed sample?

Comment: Why are you even keyword stuffing the first place?

Comment: The short answer is, Yes! It is a binary thing. If you are stuffing and Google thinks you are stuffing, you just took a serious knock to your trust score. It is not a page by page thing. It is a site trust thing.

Comment: In addition, it could end up getting your site banned from Google, Bing, and others. Not a good to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358):

> Filling pages with keywords or numbers results in a negative user experience, and can harm your site's ranking.

It's counterproductive to engage in this practice, so just don't do it.